# Python loop outputs to console

Tags: python

Why does running this code in the interactive console print output?

```
>>> def a():
...   return 1
...
>>> for i in range(3):
...   a()
...
1
1
1
>>>
```

I would expect no output. Where is this behaviour documented?

Comment: What are you confused about? The fact that you get output to the console? It should not do so without `print` statements

Comment: i ran your script, and it is giving me no output.

Comment: why would you expect something different. you are running the same function 3 times

Comment: Just to confirm, by "console" you mean "interactive prompt", right? The thing with the ">>>" prefix?

Comment: Well, you would get no output if the return value from a() is assigned to some variable or used in any other way ...

Comment: @Kevin: yes. I am speaking asking about text output by the console interpreter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In interactive mode, the result of any expression-statement is *printed* if it is not `None`. As stated in the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#expression-statements).

> Expression statements are used (mostly interactively) to compute and write a value [...]
>
> In interactive mode, if the value is not `None`, it is converted to a
>   string using the built-in `repr()` function and the resulting string is
>   written to standard output

Example:

```
>>> 1 + 1
2
>>> a()
1
>>> None # This expression is not printed
>>>
```

This is true for a expression statement in a loop as well.

```
>>> for i in range(3):
>>>     a()
1
1
1
```

Although, this is specific to the interactive shell. If you run you code as a script, nothing will be printed.

Answer (score 4):

If you use the console/interactive prompt/IDLE/shell/Python shell/potato, the values returned would be printed, and no `print()` required. This is why you can do `>>> 1+1` in the shell and it will say `2`, even though if you create a program with `1+1` it will run with no errors or output.

And a little detail: the value is not printed, its `repr` is. This is why in the shell this happens:

```
>>> print("something")
something
>>> "something"
"something"
>>> 'a string with "quotes"'
'a string with "quotes"'
```

You can do a quick test of this:

```
>>> class Test:
...     def __str__(self): return "str"
...     def __repr__(self): return "repr"

>>> test_instance = Test()
>>> test_instance
repr
>>> print(test_instance)
str
```

Answer (score 3):

This behaviour is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/appendix.html#tut-interac); you are running the Python shell in interactive mode.

Note, quoted below for posterity:

> All error messages are written to the standard error stream; **normal output from executed commands is written to standard output**.

Comment: I found this as well, but I would take "normal output" to mean *output*, not the results of expressions.

Comment: It's awkwardly worded, sure - I think I'd interpret returning as an output to the calling function, which here is the Python shell, but it's definitely ambiguous